# Enable-PSRemoting command failing in powershell, Azure VM

Tags: windows, azure, powershell

I tried the `Enable-PSRemoting` in powershell, Windows 10 Pro, configured in Azure VM.
But the command fails with the following error :

```
WinRM has been updated to receive requests.
WinRM service type changed successfully.
WinRM service started.

Set-WSManQuickConfig : <f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault" Code="2150859113"
Machine="localhost"><f:Message><f:ProviderFault provider="Config provider"
path="%systemroot%\system32\WsmSvc.dll"><f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault"
Code="2150859113" Machine="Roshin"><f:Message>WinRM firewall exception will not work since one of the network
connection types on this machine is set to Public. Change the network connection type to either Domain or Private and
try again. </f:Message></f:WSManFault></f:ProviderFault></f:Message></f:WSManFault>
At line:116 char:17
+                 Set-WSManQuickConfig -force
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-WSManQuickConfig], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WsManError,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.SetWSManQuickConfigCommand
```

Can someone help to mitigate this?

Comment: It’s literally telling you to change the network connection type to domain or private.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank  you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just missed the statment in the error :

> WinRM firewall exception will not work since one of the network
> connection types on this machine is set to Public. Change the network connection type to either Domain or Private and
> try again.

Turning the network to Private from public did the job